# UShort abbreviation?

Tags: vb.net, naming-conventions

I'm currently using visual basic and when naming variables I am shortening the data type (for example string to str, integer to int), but I don't know what to shorten UShort to. 
Any help and/or a place to find it would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean in your variable names? Like `Dim str as String` or `Dim int as Integer`? Don't do that.

Comment: NO he means int_IdiotCount, str_PresidentName....

Comment: If you mean "hungarian notation" where the data type is part of the variable name, that is no longer needed or advised.  It was useful long ago to be able to identify a variable's datatype from the name.  Today, you can use the mouse to see the type and often the scope. [General Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @plutonix, I agree using the notation is cumbersome and pointless most of the time if the name is descriptive enough. However, there are instances where it is useful to use it.. for example when you have a quantity that has a string version AND a numeric version.

Comment: Wondering why they frown on underscore... I use that all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Though there are obvious ones I'm not sure it really matters what you prefix the variable names with just as long as you are consistent and what you choose is fairly obvious.

```
Dim ush_Count as uShort
or perhaps better
Dim u16_Votes as uShort
```

Here are the common ones though

Variables : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240858(v=vs.60).aspx

Objects : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263493(v=vs.60).aspx